# Centralize text in image outputs error

Tags: numpy, opencv, unicode, python-imaging-library, python-3.5

Below code is not centralizing text no error in code, but i want to centralize text.

```
import os
unicode_text = u"\u0627\u0628\u067E"
list_of_letters = list (unicode_text) 

        char = u''.join(word) 
        t1 = arabic_reshaper.reshape(char) 
        W,H= (32, 32)
        img= PIL.Image.new('RGBA', (W, H), (255, 255, 255),)
        draw = PIL.ImageDraw.Draw(img)   
        font = PIL.ImageFont.truetype( r"C:\Downloads\arabic.ttf", 15)
        t2 = get_display(t1) 
        w, h = draw.textsize(t2.encode('utf-8'))
        draw.text(((W-w)/2,(H-h)/2), t2, fill="#000000", font=font)
```

Comment: This works fine for me with regular characters, so something is happening with your other functions here; also note that you're adding a space before the character as @usr2564301 mentions. Does the output of `draw.textsize()` make sense?

Comment: @usr2564301 please check i edited the code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not center correctly because it does not retrieve the *actual* character width and height. You can see that if you print out the character sizes that `textsize` returns and then change the font size. You still get the same character sizes!

Why does it not change? Because you load a font but then don't *use* it for measuring. If you set it inside the `draw` object, or add `font=font` to both `draw.textsize` *and* `draw.text`, it works as expected.

(Just doing that gives an error on the original `textsize` line; possibly you attempted to fix the issue in an unrelated way by adding `.encode('utf8)`. But that is not necessary.)

```
draw = PIL.ImageDraw.Draw(img)
draw.font = PIL.ImageFont.truetype( "times.ttf", 48)
t2 = get_display(t1) 
w, h = draw.textsize(t2)
draw.text(((W-w)/2,(H-h)/2), t2, fill="#000000")
print ("char: %04X w %d h %d" % (ord(char),w,h))
```

This results in correctly centered characters throughout, the same for both Latin and Arabic letters.

[image: centered colon] [image: centered capital I] [image: centered isolated teh] [image: centered isolated hah]

Comment: thanks for not only solving my issue but elaborating it in detail.