# How to always have text centred in the x-axis in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I have a text display function below:

```
def display_text(text, color, x, y, font):
    text_image = font.render(text, False, color)
    text_rect = text_image.get_rect(x=x, y=y)
    gameDisplay.blit(text_image, text_rect)
```

How would I edit this so the text displayed on the screen is always displayed in the centre of the screen but **only** in the x-axis. So I would be able to move text up and down but **never** left and right, it would always be in the centre.

Comment: Exactly as you would do manually: measure the text first. Related (but not a duplicate): see how this user did it: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48196186/2564301

Answer (score 0):

Create a rect with the size of the screen and set the `centerx` of the `text_rect` to the `screen_rect.centerx`.

```
import pygame as pg

pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
clock = pg.time.Clock()
done = False

font = pg.font.Font(None, 52)
txt_surf = font.render('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', True, (0, 100, 200))
txt_rect = txt_surf.get_rect(center=(screen_rect.centerx, 100))

while not done:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            done = True

    screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
    screen.blit(txt_surf, txt_rect)

    pg.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)
```

---

You could pass the `screen_rect.centerx` to the `display_text` function and then  to the `get_rect` method as the `center` argument.

```
import pygame as pg


def display_text(text, color, x, y, font):
    text_image = font.render(text, False, color)
    text_rect = text_image.get_rect(center=(x, 100))
    screen.blit(text_image, text_rect)


pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
clock = pg.time.Clock()
font = pg.font.Font(None, 52)
done = False

while not done:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            done = True

    screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
    display_text(
        'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', (0, 100, 200),
        screen_rect.centerx, 100, font)

    pg.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)
```